# Android Bugsense gives Exception: No peer certificate

Tags: android, bugsense

I am using bugsense 3.2.2 jar. I have a simple test code to generate NullPointerException. I am also adding a sample event & can see that in the dashboard, but could not see the crash generated.

**Inside Activity**

```
 //in onCreate()
    BugSenseHandler.I_WANT_TO_DEBUG = true;
    BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "XXXXXXXX");

 //on button click
    try{
       BugSenseHandler.sendEvent("Test button clicked!!!");
       String a = null;
       a.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
       BugSenseHandler.sendException(e);
    }

 //in onStop()
    BugSenseHandler.closeSession(this);
```

**In AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Logcat output:**

```
  04-12 17:54:34.293: W/System.err(18319): Catch exception while startHandshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x285240: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
  04-12 17:54:34.293: W/System.err(18319): return an invalid session with invalid cipher suite of SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/BugSenseHandler(18319): Transmitting ping Exception No peer certificate
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at com.bugsense.trace.models.PingsMechanism.transmitPingSync(Unknown Source)
  04-12 17:54:34.373: W/System.err(18319):  at com.bugsense.trace.models.PingsMechanism$2.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error reported above is generated as soon as the activity is started(problem seems to be in initialization code). After clicking the button there is no error, but can't see the crashes in bugsense dashboard.
I have tried with 3.2 jar too, but still the issue is same.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Also if anyone are seeing these same errors in their log, this is the response I got from the bugsense customer support "the ping exception has nothing to do with the sent of the crashes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried selecting handled tab. beacause you are handling the crash and it goes in that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that... My mistake, Now I can see it under "Handled" tab.